# Help, Error : Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I am still new to Linux and when I was trying to update Mono, I believe the part where I had to copy and paste, the echo - tee command lines is where my mistake happened. Anyhow, I can't do anything in the terminal without getting this error. I read in other forums and their solutions didn't help. I also cant paste my,  `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`, because with all the links, this website assumes I am spamming.

Typing in:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | nc termbin.com 9999
```

gives:

```
https://termbin.com/t1noy
```

which seems to change every time I type it in.

Finally, typing in:

```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official-stable.list
```

returns:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. We don't know your OS & release details, and your commands & output I find difficult to follow sorry. You mention "this error" but don't provide the actual error message, so what error?

Comment: Looks like you destroyed your list of mono sources, replacing them with a string "sudo apt-get update". It's possible, but hard to tell from your vague description, that you also corrupted or destroyed your regular (non-mono) sources. It's unclear why you want to pipe `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` through netcat (or anything else). Advice: Don't take shortcuts, and don't run commands that you don't fully understand. You need to *understand* your way out of the problem.